# Is there a way to access my JSON file outside the scope of the fetch function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I would love to get the returned value of the `fetch()` block and make use of it in another function, I tried declaring a variable outside the `fetch` and assigning it in the block but that doesn't seem to give me the desired result rather it returns undefined.

```
fetch(apiEndpoint).then(response => {
    return response.json()
}).then(jsonFile => {
    return jsonFile
})
```

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: This may also help: [JavaScript: How (not) to get a value “out of” a callback](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are trying to execute is asynchronous, that is why you see the variable outside the fetch is undefined, but, it's undefined until the request is fulfilled.
What you could do is to store the value into some king of storage (like `localstorage`) so you will have access to it in the future.

```
fetch(apiEndpoint).then(response => {
    return response.json()
}).then(jsonFile => {
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(jsonFile))
})
```

Later in another function

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))

if (data !== null) {
   // use your data
}
```

Comment: That's just a global variable that happens to be persistent; the dupe question goes into details.